# Select 2 different value from 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello i would like to select, each auction id that is associated with a bid id with status ='won' and also each auction id which status is 'Expired' as two separated column in to my statement can someone help please, the first column  will be call won and second one expired

```
SELECT 
      Auction.AuctionID, 
      DATENAME(mm, BID.Date) AS Month
FROM 
      BID INNER JOIN Auction ON BID.AuctionID = Auction.AuctionID
WHERE        
      BID.Status = 'Won'
ORDER BY Month
```

Desired result:

```
AuctionID   Month                          Won  Expired
----------- ------------------------------ ---- -------
1           January                         32    22
2           March                           10    22
3           April                            0     2
```

Comment: What data do you want want to display in those columns?

Comment: Can one auction be both won and expired?

Comment: no an auction can be either won or expired not both

Comment: So what do you need two columns for? One will always be null. Can you post (into your question) an example of what the desired output looks like for several auctions both own and expired, with the column headers and data?

Comment: What i want to display is the all auction ID that has an associated BidID where it status ='wON' AS WON  and finally all auction.id which his own status ='expired'

Comment: Please post a visual of the desired result similar to the chart in jpw's answer.

Comment: AuctionID   Month                          Won  Expired
----------- ------------------------------ ---- -------
1           January                         32    22
2           March                           10    22
3          April                             0     2

Comment: i put it but it does seem to be like to appear as a chart

Comment: @user3287068 If you group on AuctionID, what are the counts supposed to be? Doesn't one AuctionID correspond to just one Won or Expired? Or can one AuctionID have multiple corresponding bids with different status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result you want is something like this:

```
AuctionID   Month                          Won  Expired
----------- ------------------------------ ---- -------
1           January                        Won  NULL
2           January                        Won  NULL
3           January                        NULL Expired
```

Then you could use this query:

```
SELECT        
    A.AuctionID, 
    DATENAME(mm, B.Date) AS Month, 
    CASE Status WHEN 'Won' THEN 'Won' ELSE NULL END AS Won, 
    CASE Status WHEN 'Expired' THEN 'Expired' ELSE NULL END AS Expired 
FROM BID b 
INNER JOIN Auction a ON B.AuctionID = A.AuctionID
ORDER BY Month, AuctionID
```

But if the result you want is like this:

```
AuctionID   Month                          Status
----------- ------------------------------ --------------------
1           January                        Won
2           February                       Won
3           January                        Expired
```

Then this query would do:

```
SELECT        
    A.AuctionID, 
    DATENAME(mm, B.Date) AS Month, 
    Status
FROM BID b 
INNER JOIN Auction a ON B.AuctionID = A.AuctionID
ORDER BY Status Desc, Month DESC, AuctionID
```

Third try. To get this:

```
Month                          Won         Expired
------------------------------ ----------- -----------
January                        1           1
February                       1           0
```

Use this query:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(mm, B.Date) AS Month, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Won,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Expired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Expired
FROM BID b 
INNER JOIN Auction a ON B.AuctionID = A.AuctionID
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, B.Date), B.Date
ORDER BY b.Date
```

Comment: these example seem on the good way, so let me well explain what i'm doing, i'm doing a count for auction where Bidding.Status ='won' and another count where Auction.Status ='Expired', i'm going to display this result in graph

Comment: @user3287068 I added another version. I think this might be what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try something like this, its not exact just an overview

```
***

    SELECT 
          Auction.AuctionID, 
          DATENAME(mm, b1.Date) AS Month,
          COUNT(*) AS `Won`,
          (SELECT count(*) from BID b2 WHERE  DATENAME(mm, b1.Date) = DATENAME(mm, b2.Date))-COUNT(*) AS `EXPIRED` 
    FROM 
          BID b1
          INNER JOIN Auction ON BID.AuctionID = Auction.AuctionID       
    WHERE        
          BID.Status = 'Won' 
    GROUP BY Month

***
```

Answer (score 0):

An auction cannot be won and expired at the same time so you don't need to have for example : AuctionId 1 : won : 120214, expired 050214 ?

Well let's imagine it's possible :

```
with p as (
   SELECT Auction.AuctionID, DATENAME(mm, BID.Date) AS Month
   FROM BID 
   INNER JOIN Auction ON BID.AuctionID = Auction.AuctionID)

select AuctionId, max(Won), Max(Expired)
from
(
   select AuctionId, Month as Won, null as Expired from p
   WHERE (BID.Status = 'Won')
   union
   select AuctionId, null, Month from p 
   WHERE (BID.Status = 'Expired')
) z
ORDER BY Won, Expired
```

Comment: What i want to display is the all auction ID that has an associated BidID where it status ='wON' AS WON and finally all auction.id which his own status ='expired'

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
SELECT 
  Auction.AuctionID, 
  DATENAME(mm, BID.Date) AS Month,
  CASE status 
    WHEN Won THEN Status As Won
    WHEN Expired THEN Status As Expired
  END
FROM 
  BID INNER JOIN Auction ON BID.AuctionID = Auction.AuctionID
ORDER BY Month
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but in its current format this is not valid TSQL.

Comment: @David it's ok if i have written some thing wrong then i should be down voted.